# Why do correlations matter in simulating data to compare classifiers when p >> N?

Tags: classification, feature-selection

In genomics and computational biology, expression data sets contain a much larger number of features (p) than the number of observations (N). I wanted to simulate data where p>>N to compare the performance of classifier methods (e.g., regularized methods, automatic feature selection methods, and filtering/feature selection before applying any methods). In hopes of mimicking gene expression data, the informative genes were sampled from the Asymmetric Laplace Distribution (ALD) (Purdom, Holmes, 2005, suggested that gene expression data follows the ALD better than the normal distribution) and the uninformative/noisy genes were sampled from the standard normal distribution. For case 1, with n = 100 and p = 1000, 300 informative genes were sampled from X ~ ALD(-3, 0.5, 1) for class 1 and from Y ~ ALD(3, 2, 1) for class 2, and 700 uninformative/noisy genes were sampled from e ~ N(0,1). Then, 5% of the informative gene expression were transformed into outliers by increasing the scale parameter from 1 to 10. Finally, the samples (rows) were shuffled. We have E(X) = -1.93934, E(Y) = 1.93934, and Var(X) = Var(Y) = 4.761039. Here are the density curves:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3n7vrybauvste0/stackexchange.jpeg]

The red line (left pointy hat) is X, the blue line (right pointy hat) is Y, the black line is e, the orange line is X transformed into outliers, and the green line is Y transformed into outliers.

After talking to a professor about this, she suggested that I add in correlations within the features because since I am sampling independently each time, my covariance matrix for the features is the identity matrix. She suggested transforming my covariance matrix to be rho^|i-j|, where 0

My questions are:

1. **Why is it better to have the covariance matrix to be rho^|i-j| for simulation? Is that more realistic in gene expression data? Is there a specific reason why it's not all just rho in the off diagonal and 1's in the diagonal?**
2. **If I have the first 300 features to be informative and the 301th-1000th features to be noninformative (~N(0,1)), would I only add in correlations to the first 300 features? If so, would I have the covariance matrix to be {rho^|i-j| for 1 < i,j <300 if i does not equal to j, and 0 for i, j > 300 and i does not equal to j}?**

This suggestion might have been related to when I told her that my CART result revealed only one different feature in R...